# ValueListenableBuilder or StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter

In terms of performances/cost, what is the most expensive widget and what should I use if I have the choice between `ValueListenableBuilder` and `StreamBuilder` to listen changes of one variable?

Comment: Go for `ValueListenableBuilder` if you only have to listen for one variable change. I don't have anything to support my say but it's quite obvious to choose something lighter for small stuffs.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but check [this answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTzWYqr3q68&t=4330s&ab_channel=FlutterCommunity)

Answer (score 0):

ValueListenableBuilder is more use  for changes in a single variable. StreamBuilder is suitable for multiple events over time or when handling asynchronous updates. Choose based on the specific needs of your application.